# How to group genes regarding their id and position , python

Tags: python

I have a file containing genes of different genomes. Gene is denoted by NZ_CP019047.1_2993 and  Genome by NZ_CP019047
They look like this :

```
NZ_CP019047.1_2993 
NZ_CP019047.1_2994 
NZ_CP019047.1_2995 
NZ_CP019047.1_2999 
NZ_CP019047.1_3000
NZ_CP019047.1_3001
NZ_CP019047.1_3003
KE699235.1_379 
KE699235.1_1000
KE699235.1_1001
```

what I want to do is group the genes of a genome (if a genome has more than 1 gene) regarding their distance meaning, if I have genes nearer than 4 positions I want to group them together.The position can be understood as the number after '_'. I want something like these:

```
[NZ_CP019047.1_2993,NZ_CP019047.1_2994,NZ_CP019047.1_2995]
[NZ_CP019047.1_2999,NZ_CP019047.1_3000,NZ_CP019047.1_3001,NZ_CP019047.1_3003]
[KE699235.1_1000,KE699235.1_1001]
```

What I have tried so far is creating a dictionary holding for each genome, in my case NZ_CP019047 and KE699235, all the number after '_'. Then I calculate their differences, if it is less than 4 I try to group them. The problem is that I am having duplication and I am having problem in the case when 1 genome has more than 1 group of genes like this case :

```
[NZ_CP019047.1_2993,NZ_CP019047.1_2994,NZ_CP019047.1_2995]
[NZ_CP019047.1_2999,NZ_CP019047.1_3000,NZ_CP019047.1_3001,NZ_CP019047.1_3003]
```

This is my code:

```
for key in sortedDict1:
        cassette = ''
        differences = []
        numbers = sortedDict1[key]
        differences = [x - numbers[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(numbers)][1:]
        print(differences)
        for i in range(0,len(differences)):
            if differences[i] <= 3:
                pos = i
                el1 = key + str(numbers[i])
                el2 = key + str(numbers[i+1])
                cas = el1 + ' ' 
                cassette += cas
                cas = el2 + ' '
                cassette += cas
            else:
                cassette + '/n' 
                i+=1
```

I am referring to groups with variable cassette.
Can someone please help?

Comment: You didn't define sortedDict1 in your code.  Do you ignore items beginning with K i.e. KE699235.1_379?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. this is not my whole script, it is just a part of it. sortedDict1 is defined before and it the dictionary holding the key and its values but sorted, the key is the genome and the values are the numbers after  this character '_'. I ignore only genomes that have only 1 gene, in the case you are referring, I ignored KE699235.1_379 because it doesn't have any gene near, like for example KE699235.1_1000,KE699235.1_1001 the genes are consecutive because 1001-1000 = 1 which means that they form a group. their difference is 1 that is  < 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below. You can modify the labels and distances to your requirements.

```
def get_genome_groups(genome_info):
    genome_info.sort(key = lambda x: (x.split('.')[0], int(x.split('_')[-1])))
    #print(genome_info)
    genome_groups = []
    close_genome_group = []
    last_genome = ''
    position = 0
    last_position = 0

    #'NZ_CP019047.1_2995',
    for genomes in genome_info:
        genome, position = genomes.split('.')
        position = int(position.split('_')[1])

        if last_genome and (genome != last_genome):
            genome_groups.append(close_genome_group)
            close_genome_group = []

        elif close_genome_group and position and (position > last_position+3):
            genome_groups.append(close_genome_group)
            close_genome_group = []

        if genomes:
            close_genome_group.append(genomes)
        last_position = position
        last_genome = genome

    if close_genome_group:
        genome_groups.append(close_genome_group)

    return genome_groups

if __name__ == '__main__':
    genome_group = get_genome_groups(genome_info)
    print(genome_group)

user@Inspiron:~/code/general$ python group_genes.py 
[['KE699235.1_379'], ['KE699235.1_1000', 'KE699235.1_1001'], ['NZ_CP019047.1_2993', 'NZ_CP019047.1_2994', 'NZ_CP019047.1_2995'], ['NZ_CP019047.1_2999', 'NZ_CP019047.1_3000', 'NZ_CP019047.1_3001', 'NZ_CP019047.1_3003']]
user@Inspiron:~/code/general$
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. is it genome_info a dictionary?

Comment: @IIIrnr101 or a list?

Comment: It is a list of strings which you have pasted in your question.

Comment: Yes I figured it out! It works! Thank you, I really learned a lot today.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
NZ_CP019047.1_2993 
NZ_CP019047.1_2994 
NZ_CP019047.1_2995 
NZ_CP019047.1_2999 
NZ_CP019047.1_3000
NZ_CP019047.1_3001
NZ_CP019047.1_3003
KE699235.1_379 
KE699235.1_1000
KE699235.1_1001
KE6992351.2_379 
KE6992352.2_1000
KE6992353.2_1001
```

Code:

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

with open("genes.dat", "r") as msg:
    data = msg.read().splitlines()

for i, gene in enumerate(data):
    gene_name = gene.split(".")[0]
    chr_pos = gene.split(".")[1]
    data[i] = (gene_name,int(chr_pos.split("_")[0]),int(chr_pos.split("_")[1]))

data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1,2))

output = []

j = 0

for i in range(1,len(data)):
    if i == 1: 
        output.append([data[i]])

    elif data[i][1] == output[j][0][1]:
        if data[i][2] - output[j][0][2] < 5:
            output[j].append(data[i])
        else:
            output.append([data[i]])
            j += 1
    else:
         output.append([data[i]])
         j += 1

print (output)
```

Output:

```
[[('KE699235', 1, 1000), ('KE699235', 1, 1001)], [('NZ_CP019047', 1, 2993), ('NZ_CP019047', 1, 2994), ('NZ_CP019047', 1, 2995)], [('NZ_CP019047', 1, 2999), ('NZ_CP019047', 1, 3000), ('NZ_CP019047', 1, 3001), ('NZ_CP019047', 1, 3003)], [('KE6992351', 2, 379)], [('KE6992352', 2, 1000), ('KE6992353', 2, 1001)]]
```

This should make groups based on max 5 difference in position between the most backward element and the most forward in the same group.

It should work if you get a list of mixed genes considering chr location.